# TFS Build VS Test Runner - Run only tests with no TestCategory

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfsbuild, visual-studio-test-runner

I currently have around 6000+ tests running on over 30+ projects.

Some of these tests are only able to run locally, so have been decorated with the attribute:

```
TestCategory="Manual Tests"
```

this also applies to any functional tests, these are decorated with:

```
TestCategory="Functional Tests" etc...
```

I have read a number of MSDN and user articles on this and have setup a build to run only the Functional Tests

```
Test Case Filter: TestCategory=Functional Tests 
(This successfully runs only the Functional Tests)
```

Question is, is there a test case filter I could use that will ignore both the TestCategory "Functional Tests" and "Manual Tests" and only run the tests that have not been decorated with a TestCategory Attribute.

If have used the below filter cases with no joy:

```
**Test Case Filter:**

!Functional Tests|!Manual Tests
TestCategory!=Functional Tests|Manual Tests
TestCategory!=Functional Tests|!Manual Tests
TestCategory!=Functional Tests|TestCategory=Manual Tests
TestCategory!=Functional Tests||TestCategory=Manual Tests
(TestCategory!=Functional Tests)|(TestCategory=Manual Tests)
(TestCategory!=Functional Tests)||(TestCategory=Manual Tests)
```

I am running this on Visual Studio 2012 (Update 4) with TFS 2012 (Update 4)

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Fix the issue by using "()" around your filter. Also | is or, and & is and so using x!=y or y!=z will not work.  Use & for not equal to evaluations.

/TestCaseFilter:"(TestCategory!=PreTest&TestCategory!=PostTest&TestCategory!=CleanUp)"

Comment: Parenthesis was it!  Here's what I put in the TFS Test Filter criteria:  `(TestCategory!=Nightly&TestCategory!=Ignore)`.  My goal was to run all unit tests except those in the above categories.  Basically I wanted to run all tests that I didn't assign a category.

Answer (score 0):

Start small then build up..have you just tried one statement, say:
TestCategory!='Functional Tests'

Looking at the documentation my first punt for the full command would be:
TestCategory!='Functional Tests'&TestCategory!='Manual Tests'

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have a filter set a Functional Tests only build `TestCategory!=Functional Tests` and this works as expected, only this runs all tests with **no category** and tests with category = **Manual Tests**

Comment: Great have you then tried: TestCategory!='Functional Tests'&TestCategory!='Manual Tests'

Comment: I ran a build with the filter `TestCategory!='Functional Tests'&TestCategory!='Manual Tests` but unfortunately all tests are run, regardless of test category.  It looks to be ignoring the filter a defaulting to a all-test run